# Question on the go memory model,the last example

Tags: go, concurrency, atomic, memory-model

i have a  question on the go memory model.
in the last example:

```
type T struct {
    msg string
}

var g *T

func setup() {
    t := new(T)
    t.msg = "hello, world"
    g = t
}

func main() {
    go setup()
    for g == nil {
    }
    print(g.msg)
}
```

In my opnion,reads and writes of values with a single machine word is a atomic behavior.I try many times to run the test but it is always can be observed.
So please tell me why g.msg is not guarntee to observed? I want to know the reason in detail,please.

Comment: doc link : https://go.dev/ref/mem

Comment: „In my opnion,reads and writes of values with a single machine word is a atomic behavior.“ Your opinion is not backed by reality.

Comment: That may be true writing machine code directly for a certain architecture, but you’re not doing that; you’re writing Go code for all supported architectures, so only the Go memory model is relevant.

Comment: Your "opinion" is a common misconception.  It is true that on *most* machines, a load or store instruction of an aligned machine word is atomic.  But that is not *all* machines.  And more importantly, the compiler is not obligated to compile your source into the "natural" sequence of load and store instructions in the specified order, if it can achieve the same result *for this thread* with some other sequence of instructions.  So your knowledge about the memory model of any particular underlying machine is simply not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Because there are 2 write operations in the launched goroutine:

```
t := new(T)            // One
t.msg = "hello, world" // Two
g = t
```

It may be that the `main` goroutine will observe the non-`nil` pointer assignment to `g` in the last line, but since there is no explicit synchronization between the 2 goroutines, the compiler is allowed to reorder the operations (that doesn't change the behavior in the launched goroutine), e.g. to the following:

```
t := new(T)            // One
g = t
t.msg = "hello, world" // Two
```

If operations would be rearranged like this, the behavior of the launched goroutine (`setup()`) would not change, so a compiler is allowed to to this. And in this case the `main` goroutine could observe the effect of `g = t`, but not `t.msg = "hello, world"`.

<sup>Why would a compiler reorder the operations? E.g. because a different order may result in a more efficient code. E.g. if the pointer assigned to `t` is already in a register, it can also be assigned to `g` right away, without having to reload it again if the assignment to `g` would not be executed right away.</sup>

This is mentioned in the [Happens Before](https://go.dev/ref/mem#tmp_2) section:

> Within a single goroutine, reads and writes must behave as if they executed in the order specified by the program. That is, compilers and processors may reorder the reads and writes executed within a single goroutine only when the reordering does not change the behavior within that goroutine as defined by the language specification. Because of this reordering, the execution order observed by one goroutine may differ from the order perceived by another. For example, if one goroutine executes `a = 1; b = 2;`, another might observe the updated value of `b` before the updated value of `a`.

If you use proper synchronization, that will forbid the compiler to perform such rearranging that would change the observed behavior from other goroutines.

Running your example any number of times and not observing this does not mean anything. It may be the problem will never arise, it may be it will arise on a different architecture, or on a different machine, or when compiled with a different (future) version of Go. Simply do not rely on such behavior that is not guaranteed. Always use proper synchronization, never leave any data races in your app.

Comment: The revised Go memory model. [Go 1.19 Release Notes: Memory Model](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.19#mem). [The Go Memory Model, Version of June 6, 2022](https://tip.golang.org/ref/mem).

Comment: @rocka2q Go 1.19 is not yet out, the question is about the current version.